# Define location of libgcc_s.so.1

Tags: linux, dependencies, debian, libgcc

First of all I am in a Debian VPS without SUDO permissions, without possibility of installing anything.

I want to run a program:

```
./program
```

And it informs me that it needs libgcc_s.so.1:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/lib/snoopy.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
./program: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My question is, is there a way to run the program without having to install gcc-multilib (without sudo)?
I thought that maybe I could download gcc-multilib locally and specify the path in execution, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you compiled your program and on the system you are running it on, you should be a able to tell the system to load/find additional libraries in a specific directory using **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**.

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/your/custom/path/`

From the [manpage of ld.so](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> ```
>           A list of directories in which to search for ELF libraries at
>           execution time.  The items in the list are separated by either
>           colons or semicolons, and there is no support for escaping
>           either separator.
>
>           This variable is ignored in secure-execution mode.
>
>           Within the pathnames specified in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, the dynamic
>           linker expands the tokens $ORIGIN, $LIB, and $PLATFORM (or the
>           versions using curly braces around the names) as described
>           above in Rpath token expansion.  Thus, for example, the fol‐
>           lowing would cause a library to be searched for in either the
>           lib or lib64 subdirectory below the directory containing the
>           program to be executed:
>
>               $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$ORIGIN/$LIB' prog
>
>           (Note the use of single quotes, which prevent expansion of
>           $ORIGIN and $LIB as shell variables!)
> ```

Here from the error message it seems you are trying to run a 32bit binary on a 64bit system. Adding the correct 32bit libraries should allow you to run your program.

Another option would be to "simply" compile your binary for a 64bit system. But that might be problematic if you not on a native 64bit system and would probably force you to [cross compile](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).